# How to use /system/bin/linker64?

Tags: android, linker, android-shell

I want to make a code compiler/executor for Android but I don't know how to link libraries in command line, I saw that they use /system/bin/linker64 in some places but I don't know how to use this program.

****In short, can anyone tell me how to use /system/bin/linker64?
Or at least can anyone tell me I can link libraries in some other way?**** Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

12705
Var #737491CF54|737491cf54|4|d61f03c0|0|0|0|0|r-xp|/data/app/~~k7P__XJpN7YUzenHojEazA==/com.axlebolt.standoff2-D_qGukJMkbBWbE0t-dhOZg==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so|1688f54

Comment: Please explain in detail. Also, it will be good if you can attach some reference for it.